# ggplot2 grouped barchart with 2 datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have 2 data.frames that I want to plot together with a grouped barchart.

The first dataframe is a stacked barchart with multiple colors and a corresponding axis on the left.

The second dataframe is a single barchart with one color only and the corresponding axis on the right.

The image below illustrates my goal:

[image]

Here is my dataset and my failing attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2019-01-29", class = "factor"), 
                      streckenabschn = c("something", "something", "something", "something"), 
                      variable = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                      value = c(0, 0, 2, 8)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(day = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2015-12-25", "2019-01-29"), class = "factor"), 
                      streckenabschn = c("something", "something"), 
                      variable = c("x", "x"), value = c(0.6, 3.471875)), 
                 row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")


cbPalette <- c('#3652a3', '#60a0df', '#b7dbff', '#dd0000', "gray")
legendLabels <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "x")
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df1, aes(x=day, y=value, fill = variable),
           stat = "identity", width=0.2) +
  geom_bar(data = df2, aes(x=day, y=value, fill = variable),
           stat = "identity", width=0.2, position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=cbPalette, labels=legendLabels) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Axis 2")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Legend", nrow = 2, ncol=4, byrow = T)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") + ylab("Axis 1")
```

**My Problems:**

- How can I have 1 barchart that is stacked, while the other one is
  "dodged"?
- How can I define the "Axis 2" labels and breaks to
  correspond to the data, since I cannot use a transformation formula?

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both datasets into one, do a bit of manual preprocessing for the x position and then plot:

```
library(dplyr)
w = 0.2
bind_rows(df1, df2, .id="src") %>% 
  mutate(x0 = as.integer(factor(day)),
         dx = c(-w/2, w/2)[as.integer(factor(src))]) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(day, value)) +
  geom_blank(aes(x = day, y = value)) + # useful to get correct labelling of axes
  geom_bar(aes(x = x0 + dx, y = value, fill = variable),
           stat = "identity", width = w) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = cbPalette, labels = legendLabels) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme_light() + theme(legend.position = "top")
```

#### Secondary axis

Using secondary vertical axes is discouraged in ggplot, but if you really need it you can specify a custom transformation function (linear rescaling) and use [`sec_axis`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html)

First define two rescaling functions:

```
# Functions scaling ticks and values for using secondary scale
# !! This is visually OK but lacks interpretability. 
# Preferrable to use business-derived hardcoded ratio !!

# Helper function
get_max_height = function(df) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(day) %>% 
    summarize(h = sum(value)) %>% 
    with(max(h))
}
ratio_1_2 = get_max_height(df1) / get_max_height(df2)

# from scale of df2 to scale of df1:
trans_values = function(v2) {
  v2 * ratio_1_2  
}
# from scale of df1 to scale of df2:
trans_ticks = function(v1) {
  v1 / ratio_1_2
}
```

And then use them in the data frame and graph axes:

```
bind_rows(
  df1 %>% mutate(day = as.character(day), y = value),
  df2 %>% mutate(day = as.character(day), y = trans_values(value)),
  .id="src"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    x0 = as.integer(factor(day)),
    dx = c(-w/2, w/2)[as.integer(factor(src))]
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_blank(aes(day)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x0 + dx, y, fill = variable),
           stat = "identity", width = w) +
  scale_y_continuous("Values 1", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans_ticks, "Values 2")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = cbPalette, labels = legendLabels) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme_light() + theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just edited my answer, since I managed to get the legend correctly. I also included the `sec_axis` but I dont have a transformation formula for those values. I know it is discouraged, but sometimes it is really very useful.

Comment: I added it to my answer. Hope you will use it carefully ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting this error `Error: transformation for secondary axes must be a formula`

Comment: do you have v3.2.0 of ggplot2? Anyway, it would be trivial to write the formula equivalent to `trans_ticks`

Comment: No, I'm on 3.1.0

Comment: Can you explain why the color mapping changes when I use different characters for `variable`? Is it internally sorted alphabetically?

Comment: you mean that the modalities of `variable` are sorted alphabetically in the colour guide? If you have a preferred order you can `factor()` it with that levels order

Comment: Yes, if the variables are not a,b,c,d,x but something else.. It is apparently mapped alphabetically. Thanks a lot!